# Annotating any files

Tags: files, filesystems, linker, file-metadata

I have had this problem for a very long time, had several discussions with friends, and tried searching relating info online. All efforts were in vain so I decide to give a shot here.

I have lots of files that I would like to annotate. Not necessarily are they pictures or documents, but also audio/video files. Now, I understand that there are ways to annotate a PDF, and there are ways to add metadata to PDF/mp3/mp4.., but those methods are not enough for me.

More specifically, when it comes to PDF files, usually I would like to take some notes in my favorite format. The current best way I can think of is to create another file with the same name and put them in the same directory (or tar them together), e.g. `Learn-How-to-Learn.pdf` `Learn-How-to-Learn.pdf.note.md`. However, I found this method cumbersome, for instance it is hard to always link them together and with their names synced.

When it comes to mp3/mp4 files, I also want to link them to other files that contain my notes. For example,

```
00:45:37,I would like to listen to this part again,20190610T19:03:56
01:03:55,Donald Knuth made a good point on blah blah,20190610T20:00:03
```

These examples go on and on.. I feel that this is very useful, and there must be some clever solutions out there. But to my surprise, I haven't found any! Please let me know if I should be clearer.. sincerely I would like to have a beautiful solution. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, it would be something like https://github.com/ljmdullaart/a-notate. Yes, it is written (by me) after you asked this question, and it is inspired on your question.

Comment: It's thrilling to hear that you write a script for my question. I am still testing it, but perhaps a minor suggestion will be helpful: `file2do=$(pwd)/$1`. Other than that, I am still testing it (and having fun). Also, I really like the way you shell script. Would you mind sharing Andreas Kusalananda Khäri's lesson in cleaner shell programming? I cannot find it online.

Comment: Another feature (bug?) that I found confusing in the script is that around line 40, using `grep -q blahblab`  seems not enough for me. The file `overview` will not be updated if the name of file is changed to a substring of the original one. For example, changing `README.md` to `README.m` is not a good idea under this system. Instead, regex saves the day by adding `$` in the end of the string to be matched: `grep -q ":$file2do"$`.

Comment: Some updates done; please let further comment on the script go via git.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me into hashing. I believe that's the only thing I missed for making such a script come true. I did also branch your repo and make some change, and will keep working on that.